# Netty options for real-time distribution of small messages to a large number of clients?

Tags: java, real-time, netty, out-of-memory

I am designing a (near) real-time Netty server to distribute a large number of very small messages to a large number of clients across the internet.  In internal, go as fast as you can testing, I found that I could do 10k clients no sweat, but now that we are trying to go across the internet, where the latency, bandwidth etc varies pretty wildly we are running into the dreaded outOfMemory issues, even with 2 gigs of RAM.

I have tried various workarounds(setting the socket stack sizes smaller, setting high and low water marks, cancelling things that are too old), and they help a little, but they seem to only help a little bit.  What would some good ways to optimize Netty for sending large #s of small messages without significant delays?   Also, the bulk of the message only consists of one kind of message that I don't particularly care if it doesn't arrive.  I would use UDP but because we don't control the client, thats not really a possibility.  Is it possible to set a separate timeout solely for this kind of message without affecting the other messages?

Any insight you could offer would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

usually, if see outOfMemory you can use a thread dump tool to dump the threads. Or use something like jvirtualvm and jconsole to find out which class doesn't get GCed and keep eating your memory.
2Gigs is not big for 64 bit machines nowadays.Try to turn that a number bigger to about 3 or 4 G to see if you don't hit OOM.
If you find you can handle 10k connections easily in LAN, try to add a small delay in your netty handler. Check what happens.

Comment: I did, and it wasn't very enlightening, not surprisingly most of the memory was taken up by Netty buffers and ChannelFuture objects

Comment: have you checked the gc time under pressure? You can add a channel group inside your handler and check how many concurrent channels are hold with/without connection delay

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look into [load balancing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Load_balancing_%28computing%29) approach. It is used to distribute the workload across the distributed system using both hardware and software. The details of what is suitable for your system depend on several factors which includes hardware upgrade, etc. Certainly, 2GB of RAM is fairly small to server 10k users and you will need to increase this limit.

Comment: We use load balancing(the server processes incoming messages, distributes it among the servers via a Redis pub/sub, and then each server distributes it to the users connected to it), but we are still running into problems, esp. with slow clients...

Comment: i see. it wasn't clear from your post. i was impressed that you could serve such high demands using just 2GB of RAM.

Answer (score 0):

You don't say whether the subscription stream is constant or bursty. You also don't say whether there is a minimum number of messages / second the client must support.

Given that I don't know anything about Redis, are any of the following practical?

- For the messages you don't care about, if channel.isWritable() == false, discard immediately. Unfortunately I don't know of a way to cancel messages that are in Netty's send buffer. You wouldn't be able to cancel messages that have been passed to the TCP send buffer anyway so it's not really something to rely on.
- Slow reception from the subscription to the rate of the slowest client.
- Determine which clients can't keep up (maybe use the write timeout handler) and move them to a separate subscription which can be slowed down. Duplicate the published messages to both subscriptions.
- Can you split the messages to send to the clients across different subscriptions. If a client can't keep up unsubscribe it from the unimportant messages.

If your average send rate is higher than the client can support over time then there isn't really a solution other than negotiating a change in requirements to reduce the maximum allowable throughput.

Comment: Sorry, I meant that Redis was sharing amongst the servers, there is no problem on the back-end, just the front-end which is all Netty to a TCP client.  How can I use a write timeout to slow down sending to slow clients?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't make myself clear. I'm suggesting that if it's possible to calculate an average speed, and therefore the longest it should take to write a message to the network, you can use WriteTimeoutHandler to determine if a client has fallen behind and take some kind of avoiding action, such as subscribing to a slower subscription or dropping the client.